# DELETE Entries from Database with LEFT JOIN

Tags: php, mysql, sql

i have troubles finding the right sql-statement

I have 3 tables:

```
1.) Messages
2.) Mail_Inbox
3.) Mail_Outbox
```

New Messages are stored in Messages and its ID is stored in both other tables.
User can delete their mails from inbox and outbox folder.

I want du parse a single sql-statement to delete all entries from Messages where no entries in Inbox AND Outbox with the corresponding ID exsits.

I still found a working statement, which tells me the right IDs, but i can't find a way to delete them.

```
SELECT Messages.Message_ID 
FROM `Messages` 
LEFT JOIN Mail_Inbox On Messages.Message_ID = Mail_Inbox.Message_ID 
LEFT JOIN Mail_Outbox On Messages.Message_ID = Mail_Outbox.Message_ID 
WHERE ISNULL(Mail_Outbox.Mail_ID) AND ISNULL(Mail_Outbox.Mail_ID)
```

I tried this:

```
DELETE FROM Messages 
WHERE Message_ID = (SELECT Messages.Message_ID 
                    FROM `Messages` 
                    LEFT JOIN Mail_Inbox On Messages.Message_ID = Mail_Inbox.Message_ID 
                    LEFT JOIN Mail_Outbox On Messages.Message_ID = Mail_Outbox.Message_ID 
                    WHERE ISNULL(Mail_Outbox.Mail_ID) AND ISNULL(Mail_Outbox.Mail_ID))
```

But got this error: You can't specify target table 'Messages' for update in FROM clause

:-(

Comment: Your select will find messages from inbox. You need to change your `WHERE`to something like `ISNULL(Mail_Inbox.Mail_ID) AND ISNULL(Mail_Outbox.Mail_ID)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not possible to use a table you want to delete from inside s subquery as per [DELETE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/delete.html)-documentation

```mysql
SELECT
  Messages.Message_ID
FROM `Messages`
  LEFT JOIN Mail_Inbox ON Messages.Message_ID = Mail_Inbox.Message_ID
  LEFT JOIN Mail_Outbox ON Messages.Message_ID = Mail_Outbox.Message_ID
WHERE ISNULL(Mail_Inbox.Mail_ID) AND ISNULL(Mail_Outbox.Mail_ID)
```

becomes

```mysql
DELETE
  Messages
FROM `Messages`
  LEFT JOIN Mail_Inbox ON Messages.Message_ID = Mail_Inbox.Message_ID
  LEFT JOIN Mail_Outbox ON Messages.Message_ID = Mail_Outbox.Message_ID
WHERE ISNULL(Mail_Inbox.Mail_ID) AND ISNULL(Mail_Outbox.Mail_ID)
```

Comment: Er, there is some scope for improvement

Comment: @Strawberry you're right. I just copied from question, which erounosly double-checks for presence in mail_outbox.

Answer (score -2):

```
DELETE FROM Messages WHERE Message_ID IN (some subquery that select Message_IDs)
```

Your current subquery will give you all Message_IDs and will delete all messages because you use a LEFT JOIN. Use INNER JOIN.

Comment: `INNER JOIN` will not lead to the rigth results. `LEFT JOIN` combined with checking for `NULL`.values in the fk-column will give isolated rows. `INNER JOIN` could only give the rows you want to keep.